# Etymology of the Swissgerman word "gnusch"

Tags: etymology, swiss-german

Weiss jemand etwas zur Etymologie, zur Herkunft des wunderbaren schweizerdeutschen Wortes "Gnusch"?

Comment: Was heißt es denn? Ein bisschen Zusatzinfo wäre nett :)

Answer (score 5):

Es existieren zwei mundartliche Varianten: *«G'nusch»* und *«G'nosch»* (Unordnung). Hier handelt es sich um eine [alemannische](http://als.wikipedia.org/) Substantivierung des Verbes **[nosche<sup>n</sup>](http://digital.idiotikon2.ch/idtkn/id4.htm#page/40833/mode/1up)** (suchend in etwas herumwühlen und es dadurch in Unordnung bringen).

Letzteres Verb kommt, bzw. kam regional auch außerhalb der Schweiz vor:

> **[nüschen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN06598)** *bairisch* herumriechen, herumsuchen wie die Schweine. *plattdeutsch:* etwas mit der Nase durchwühlen wie die Schweine und Hunde.

---

Denkbar wäre auch eine in Zusammenhang von verborgenen (politischen) Machenschaften gebrauchte Bildung *«G'nusch»* als Substantivierung des Verbs *nusche<sup>n</sup>*.

> **[nuschere / nusche<sup>n</sup>:](http://digital.idiotikon2.ch/idtkn/id4.htm#page/40833/mode/1up)**  1. näselnd undeutlich leise reden. 
>   2. über die Verrichtung kleinlicher Dinge die Hauptgeschäfte versäumen. 
>   3. sich im Geheimen nach etwas umsehen. 
>   4. *nüschere:* unrechte Dinge im Verborgenen tun, heimlich etwas in die Tasche stecken.

Comment: Also ich kenne _Gnusch_ nur in der zweiten Bedeutung (Unordung, Durcheinander). So ist es bei uns recht verbreitet. _Gnosch_ würde ich lediglich als regionale Aussprachevariante (Appenzell?) demselben Wort zuordnen.

Comment: @PMF: gut zu wissen, dann sortiere ich die Antwort um :)